# DIY - Pinch to Zoom for mobile with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, pinchzoom

in my project I came across with a need for pinch to zoom support, but not the basic one.

and there are two main "must have" while doing so.

1) only the DIV container will zoom, and not the rest of the page (eg: top bar)
2) I need to keep the window basic scroll

I've added a simple code showing how I've done so and it left me with 2 questions

I) the page is jumpy while I'm pinching for zoom. 
II) have I calculate this correctly? or should I have it another way?

*** you can find a working example in the link below**

https://www.klika.co.il/canvas/pinch.html

```js
        // ----------- TOUCH -------------- 

        //handles on move events for tracking touches
       

        var touches = {
            points: null,

            start: function (e) {
                if (gesture.is.on) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    if (e.preventDefault)
                        e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }
                //reset touches
                touches.points = null;
                msg('touch start');
            },

            move: function (e) {
               // msg('touch move');

                if (e.touches.length > 1) {
                   // msg('touch move ' + e.touches.length + ' fingers');

                    //set touches only if two fingers are on
                    touches.points = { x: {}, y: {} }
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.touches.length; i++) {
                        touches.points.x[i] = e.touches[i].clientX;
                        touches.points.y[i] = e.touches[i].clientY;
                    }
                }
            },

            end: function (e) {
                msg('touch end');
            }
        };


        // ----------- GESTURE -------------- 


        var gesture = {
            is: {
                on: false,
                init: false
            },

            data: {
                content: null,
                elem: null,
                width: 0,
                state: {},
            },

            start: function (e) {
                gesture.is.on = true;
                msg('gesture start');

                gesture.data.content = $('.containter')[0];
                gesture.data.elem = $('.containter .wrap')[0];

                gesture.data.width = toFloat(gesture.data.elem.style.width, 100);

                gesture.is.init = true;
            },

            move: function (e) {
                if (!touches.points) { return; }

                //set the body element for Y axis
                const el = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;

                //set mid points
                var X1 = touches.points.x[0];
                var Y1 = touches.points.y[0];

                var X2 = touches.points.x[1];
                var Y2 = touches.points.y[1];

                var mid = getMidPoint(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);

                //set start position on init
                if (gesture.is.init) {

                    gesture.data.state = {
                        w: gesture.data.width / 100,
                        sl: ((gesture.data.content.scrollLeft + mid.x) / gesture.data.content.scrollWidth) * 100,
                        st: ((el.scrollTop + mid.y) / el.scrollHeight) * 100,
                        mid: mid
                    }

                    gesture.is.init = false;
                }


                //calc/set width of the wrapping DIV
                var inc = e.scale * gesture.data.state.w;

                var WPX = gesture.data.content.scrollWidth * inc;
                var HPX = document.body.scrollHeight * inc;

                var w = (WPX / gesture.data.content.scrollWidth) * 100;

                gesture.data.elem.style.width = w + '%';


                //calc/set scrollLeft of the wrapping DIV (X axis)
                var sln = Math.round(((gesture.data.state.sl / 100) * gesture.data.content.scrollWidth) - (getWindowXY().w / 2));
                if (sln < 0) { sln = 0; }
                sln += gesture.data.state.mid.x - mid.x;

                gesture.data.content.scrollLeft = sln;


                //calc/set scrollLeft of the body element (Y axis)
                var slt = Math.round(((gesture.data.state.st / 100) * el.scrollHeight) - (getWindowXY().h / 2));
                if (slt < 0) { slt = 0; }
                slt += gesture.data.state.mid.y - mid.y;

                el.scrollTop = slt;
            },

            end: function (e) {

                var w = toFloat(gesture.data.elem.style.width);

                if (isNaN(w) || w < 100) {
                    gesture.data.elem.style.width = '100%';
                }

                gesture.is.on = false;
            }
        }


        // -------- BIND ------

        window.addEventListener('touchstart', touches.start, false);
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', touches.move, true);
        window.addEventListener('touchend', touches.end, true);

        window.addEventListener('gesturestart', gesture.start, false);
        window.addEventListener('gesturechange', gesture.move, false);
        window.addEventListener('gestureend', gesture.end, false);


        //------ GENERAL --------

        String.prototype.format = function () {
            var s = this,
                i = arguments.length;

            if (!s) {
                return "";
            }

            while (i--) {
                s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
            }
            return s;
        }

        var toFloat = function (val) {
            return parseFloat(val.replace("%", ""));
        }

        var getWindowXY = function () {
            var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
            if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                //Non-IE
                myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 4 compatible
                myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
            }
            return {
                h: myHeight,
                w: myWidth
            }
        }

        var msg = function (text) {
            $('.info').html(text);
        }

        var getMidPoint = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            return { x: ((x1 + x2) / 2), y: ((y1 + y2) / 2) }
        }

        window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        };

        window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            if (e.message == "Script error.") { return; }
            if (e.message.indexOf('facebook') != -1) { return; }

            msg(e.message);
        }, false);
```

```css
   body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width:100vw;
        }

        .top{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            line-height: 40pt;
            text-align: center;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 20pt;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .top .info{

        }

        .containter {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }

        .containter .wrap {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .containter .wrap img {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 30pt;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Pinch to zoom</title>

    <script src="https://www.klika.co.il/plugins/jqTools/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="info">Pinch to zoom</div>
    </div>

    <div class="containter">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/91858/594887747/stock-photo-dreams-of-travel-child-flying-on-a-suitcase-against-the-backdrop-of-sunset-594887747.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1020994/556702975/stock-photo-portrait-of-a-happy-and-proud-pregnant-woman-looking-at-her-belly-in-a-park-at-sunrise-with-a-warm-556702975.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/234100/599187701/stock-photo-funny-little-girl-plays-super-hero-over-blue-sky-background-superhero-concept-599187701.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1316512/661476343/stock-photo-funny-pineapple-in-sunglasses-near-swimming-pool-661476343.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2114402/689953639/stock-photo-adult-son-hugging-his-old-father-against-cloudy-sky-with-sunshine-689953639.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/172762/705978841/stock-photo-businessman-looking-to-the-future-for-new-business-opportunity-705978841.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>


    
</body>
</html>
```